# Aligining item descriptions

Tags: lists, indentation, enumitem, description

I am trying to make my description list with same margin as my formulas (made with `fleqn` option - `\usepackage[fleqn]{mathtools}`). I was able to make it with `labelindent` option of the `description` environment, but now item labels are placed on item descriptions. `leftmargin` option helps, but I have to specify it each use of `description` environment.

Is there any way to automate it ?

```
\begin{description}[labelindent=25pt,style=multiline,leftmargin=2.5cm]
    \item[$mc^2$] \lipsum[1]
    \item[$L_{ongest}$] \lipsum[2]
    \item[$L_p$] \lipsum[3]
\end{description}
```

Is it possible to set those options globally, but only for `description` environment?

Comment: See documentation of enumitem, section 5, global settings.

Comment: Thanks, that's all I need about 2nd part of my question ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Global list options are set using [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem)'s `\setlist[<list>]{<style>}` option. Here's a minimal example showing how *only* the `description` environment `<style>` is set globally:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{enumitem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem
\setlist[description]{labelindent=25pt,style=multiline,leftmargin=2.5cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{description}
  \item[$mc^2$] \lipsum[1]
  \item[$L_{ongest}$] \lipsum[2]
  \item[$L_p$] \lipsum[3]
\end{description}

\begin{itemize}
  \item \lipsum[4]
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

All levels of `description` is set according to the given `<style>`. If you want this to be localized to a specific `<level>`, use `\setlist[description,<level>]{<style>}`.

For more information on global setting, see section **5 Global settings** (p 9) of the [`enumitem` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf).

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that this only works with newish versions of `enumitem`. For example, the version in TL09 (which sadly, is still the version in the debian repos) doesn't have this useful `\setlist` thing…

Comment: @Seamus: Yes, that true. Not sure when "this useful `\setlist` thing" came into play, but it's been "calc-savvy" since 3.0 (according to the [`enumitem` README](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/README)).

Comment: Thanks for the full answer (and my post edit, still learning english).